# Caesar Cipher encoder in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, encryption

I am trying to make a simple program with python to encode a string with a certain shift using the Caesar cipher but my code does not seem to work right.

Here is my code:

```
n = int(input())
s = list(input())
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == " ":
        new = 32
    else:
        if s[i].isupper():
            new = ord(s[i]) + n
            while new > 122:
                new -= 26
        else:
            new = ord(s[i]) + n
            while new > 90:
                new -= 24
    s[i] = chr(new)
print ("".join(s))
```

What do you think is wrong here?

A test case is:

12

Qx Bek Oazsdaa

This should return:

El Psy Congroo

Answer (score 0):

Your 122 and 90 are in the wrong positions, and 24 should be 26.

```
n = int(input())
s = list(input())
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == " ":
        new = 32
    else:
        if s[i].isupper():
            new = ord(s[i]) + n
            while new > 90:
                new -= 26
        else:
            new = ord(s[i]) + n
            while new > 122:
                new -= 26
    s[i] = chr(new)
print ("".join(s))
```

Result:

```
2
Hello abc XYZ
Jgnnq cde ZAB
```

Comment: Still failing cases :(

Comment: Which cases are those?